# jQuery Selectbox to Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before changing country

[image]

After changing country

[image]

As you saw on the pictures i want to replace selectbox with textbox for city and town depends on changing country. (I need selectbox only in my country. For other countries i need textbox.)

If the client change country i'm replacing selectbox to textbox. It is ok. But if the client want to back old country selection I need to reload city and town as selectbox. But it is not working

What should i do ?

Here is my jquery file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var city = $('#city').html();
        var town = $('#town').html();

        $('#country').change(function(city, town){
            var country = $(this).val();
            if(country != 'Türkiye')
            {
                $('#city').replaceWith('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" id="city">');
                $('#town').replaceWith('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="town" id="town">');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#city').replaceWith(city);
                $('#town').replaceWith(town);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE:** I'm almost done. (I used @Rhumborl 's method.)

But there is a problem. Town depends on city selection. Normally when city changes i'm loading new towns. But in this issue. It is not working.

In this event code fails.

1. I changed country.
2. I turned back Turkey.
3. I changed city to Ankara, new towns are loading from Ankara.
4. When i changed any other country and turn back to Turkey. I can see city as Ankara. But towns are not Ankara's. Towns are from origin City Nevşehir.

Here is screenshot

[image]

This is conflict.

Comment: `if(country != 'Türkiye')` is this right, the image show `Turkey`?

Comment: Based on the selected city, where are the town names acquired from? From ajax response or the town names are hardcoded?

Comment: town names are retrieved from database as ajax response

Comment: @CihanKüsmez I've post another answer below. This time the town names acquired from ajax response. I use jsfiddle's ajax mock so there will be few lines of code that needs to be changed according to your situation. If you could provide URL of ajax request (of town names) that publicly accessible that would be great. Cheers.

Comment: I have updated my answer for the update issue.

Comment: I think it is easier to have two city fields (select and text box) on the form and to hide / show them and get value from the corresponding field based on country value.

Answer (score 8):

try this:-

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        var city = $('#city');
        var town = $('#town');

        $('#country').change(function(){

            var country = $(this).val();
            if(country != 'Türkiye')
            {
                $('#city').replaceWith('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" id="city">');
                $('#town').replaceWith('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="town" id="town">');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#city').replaceWith(city);
                $('#town').replaceWith(town);
            }
        });
    });
```

remove `.html()` as that gets the content inside the element and remove the `city` and `town` parameters in the function.

**EDIT**

If you have event handlers attached to `city` and `town` selects, wire your events like so:-

```
$(document).on('change', 'select#city', function(){

$(document).on('change', 'select#town', function(){
```

that way the events on the selects you were originally losing will still work as you need. `select#city` will only target the select and not the text field.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/n8yzzv47/)

**EDIT FOR CITY CHANGE**

To fix this, just reset the city and town variables on city `change`.

ie:-

```
$(document).on('change', '#city', function(){

     //YOUR CODE FOR SETTING THE TOWNS HERE

     // RE-SET CITY AND TOWN
     city = $('#city');
     town = $('#town');
 });
```

See this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/n8yzzv47/1/)

Comment: ok it is working but i have a different problem now. If client decided to change city. I need to load towns of that city. In fact it is working. But in this situation it is not working. Why ?

Answer (score 8):

You have 2 issues

1. `html()` only gives you the `innerHTML` of an element, that is any content *inside* it, not the element itself. In this case, you will only get the `<option>`s.
2. Your change function is taking in 2 parameters called `city` and `town` which are overriding the references to the variables you create at the top. Because this function will be given the jQuery event object, you are replacing the textboxes with the wrong things.

To fix problem 1, you can simply remove the `.html()` part, and just store `city` and `town` as jQuery objects containing the original elements.

To fix problem 2, just remove the `city` and `town` parameters from your function.

So your code can look like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var city = $('#city');
    var town = $('#town');

    $('#country').change(function(){
        var country = $(this).val();
        if(country != 'Türkiye')
        {
            $('#city').replaceWith('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" id="city">');
            $('#town').replaceWith('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="town" id="town">');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#city').replaceWith(city);
            $('#town').replaceWith(town);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="country">
  <option value="Türkiye">Turkey</option>
  <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
</select>

<select id="city">
  <option value="Izmir">Izmir</option>
  <option value="Ankhara">Ankha`enter code here`ra</option>
</select>

<select id="town">
  <option value="Merkez">Merkez</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to keep event handlers etc attached to `town` and `city` selects, you cannot use `replaceWith()` as this removes all event handlers. As the documentation says:

> The .replaceWith() method removes all data and event handlers
>   associated with the removed nodes.

Instead you need a combination of [`detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) to remove the elements but preserve event handlers and [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) to add the inputs/selects to the DOM after the current active elements:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var city = $('#city');
    var town = $('#town');
  
    town.change(function() {
      $('#townResult').text($(this).val());
    });
  
    city.change(function() {
      $('#cityResult').text($(this).val());
    });

    $('#country').change(function(){
        var country = $(this).val();
        if(country != 'Türkiye')
        {
            // add the textboxes after the dropdowns, then detach the dropdowns
            $('#city').after('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" id="city">').detach();
            $('#town').after('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="town" id="town">').detach();
        }
        else
        {
            // add the dropdowns after the textboxes, then remove the textboxes
            $('#city').after(city).remove();
            $('#town').after(town).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="country">
  <option value="Türkiye">Turkey</option>
  <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
</select>

<select id="city">
  <option value="Izmir">Izmir</option>
  <option value="Ankhara">Ankhara</option>
</select>

<select id="town">
  <option value="Merkez">Merkez</option>
  <option value="A Town">A Town</option>
</select>

<div id="cityResult"></div>
<div id="townResult"></div>
```

Comment: ok. It works. But i have a newer issue now. For example client change country and turn back to Turkey again. I got my selectboxes. But when client change the city i cannot ajax loading towns for that city. It is not working. Normally it works.

Comment: @CihanKüsmez I have added a second option to handle this situation

Comment: Dear @Rhumborl yesterday i made some tests. And i saw that i'm not done. Problem is Normally town has no options. I'm selecting depends on city change. I'veupdated question.

Answer (score 4):

You can add the element that you want to replace inside a container ( a div or a span) then replace the whole container content with the needed element depending on your requirements

Answer (score 3):

You can use html templates :

```
<script type="text/html" id="textbox-template"><!-- Your textbox here --></script>

<script type="text/html" id="selectbox-template"><!-- Your selectbox here --></script>
```

With jQuery, load the content of the corresponding template depending of the selected country.

If you wan't to save and re-display selected values, you can save the current textbox or selectbox html in the corresponding template.

Answer (score 3):

You are almost right. Just you need to replace these three lines of code.

Code(Before Replace) :

```
var city = $('#city').html();
        var town = $('#town').html();

        $('#country').change(function(city, town){
```

Replace with this(After Replace):

```
var city = $('#city');
        var town = $('#town');

        $('#country').change(function(){
```

Answer (score 3):

Another proposed solution. This one the list of town name acquired from AJAX.

The returned list of town name is mocked (hard coded) to mimic the real condition. You should change the code below the `// FIXME: list of town should be acquired from server.`. Change the `townList` variable with the list of town acquired from server.

> Checkout my answer on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marson/4ouce2cf/)

*PS : I am not including the code here because AJAX request/response can't be mimicked here.*

Answer (score 2):

Please find my proposed solution below. 
Assuming that town names are hard coded,not from AJAX response, I've added array of town values & names corresponded to city.

You can also check the same snippet on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marson/bsuffrr3/1/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var city = $('#city');
  var town = $('#town');
  $('#country').change(function() {
    var country = $(this).val();
    if (country != 'Türkiye') {
      $('#city').replaceWith('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" id="city">');
      $('#town').replaceWith('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="town" id="town">');
    } else {
      $('#city').replaceWith(city);
      $('#town').replaceWith(town);
    }
  });
  // Need to attach event handlers to newly inserted city & town options
  $(document).on('change', '#city', function() {
    var city = $(this).val();
    // Clear town options 
    $("#town").html("");
    // Then append town names based on selected city
    for (var i = 0; i < towns[city].length; i++) {
      $("#town").append("<option value='" + towns[city][i].val + "' >" + towns[city][i].label + "</option>");
    }
  });
  // Town names. Assuming town names are hard coded, correspond to city name.
  // Note: value of town names in HTML has been changed to number based value (0 & 1)
  var towns = [
    [{
      val: "merkez",
      label: "Merkez"
    }, {
      val: "izmirtowna",
      label: "Izmir Town A"
    }],
    [{
      val: "ankharatowna",
      label: "Ankhara Town A"
    }, {
      val: "ankharatownb",
      label: "Ankhara Town B"
    }]
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
<select id="country">
  <option value="Türkiye">Turkey</option>
  <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
  <option value="USA">USA</option>
</select>
<select id="city">
  <option value="0">Izmir</option>
  <option value="1">Ankhara</option>
</select>
<select id="town">
  <option value="Merkez">Merkez</option>
  <option value="izmirtowna">Izmir Town A</option>
</select>
```